# How to run a local host that continues to serve until a keyword stops it, all from a .py file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, server, localhost

When I run a local host server to view my html files, I usually use the command line prompt:

`python -m http.server 8000`

However, I want to be able to do this from within a .py file, and I'm struggling.
Ideally when running the py file it should launch the server, open the localhost in the default web browser, and then remain open until the user types in a keyword, like 'exit'. As per the http.server documentation, my current code looks like this:

```
import http.server
import socketserver
import webbrowser

PORT = 8000
URL = f'localhost:{PORT}/MapViz.html'

def run():
    Handler = http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
    with socketserver.TCPServer(("", PORT), Handler) as httpd:
          print("Enjoy your visualization!")
          httpd.serve_forever()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()
    webbrowser.open_new(URL)
```

I know at the moment it has nothing to close the server after the user is done, but I'm just struggling to get it to open the browser first. It seems like `serve_forever()` is not the right tool for the job, but I'm not sure what is.

Also, do I need to worry about closing the socket? I've always been able to use a `with open(x) as file:` format for files to not worry about closing them, but I had an issue while messing with this where I got a Windows error 10048, stating that the socket was still being used, so maybe it's also not closing correctly.

Thank you!

Comment: You could try to call something like `threading.Timer(1.0, webbrowser.open_new, URL).start()` before calling `run()` or instead run the server in a separate thread.

Comment: Wow, that worked excellently, thank you! I'll have to read more about threading, since it seems very powerful. I'll experiment a bit more to see if I can come up with a solution to getting it to close properly and then update with an answer. Thank you so much again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution I am using!

```
import http.server
import socketserver
import webbrowser
import threading
import sys

PORT = 8000
URL = f'http://localhost:{PORT}/MapViz.html'

def run():
    Handler = http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
    global httpd
with socketserver.TCPServer(("", PORT), Handler) as httpd:
    print(f"Enjoy your visualization!")
    httpd.serve_forever()

def maintain():
     webbrowser.open_new(URL)
while True:
    user_input = input()
    if user_input == 'EXIT' or user_input == 'exit':
        print('Shutting down! Run this .exe again to view your visualization again.')
        threading.Timer(0.1, httpd.shutdown).start()
        break

if __name__ == '__main__':
    threading.Timer(1.0, maintain).start()
    run()
```

I tweaked the code Michael gave me ever so slightly and had threading.Timer call an entirely new function, which both opened the window in a browser and checked for the kill-word. 
I am sure my shutdown is not the most efficient way, but does what I need it to. I will definitely need to look into more threading examples to find how best